# Ignore specific collection in mongodb for replication

Tags: mongodb, replication

We have a mongodb setup in replica set with a primary, secondary and arbiter. My question is that if we have a specific collection for which we do not need replication, how can that be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

Copy it to the `local` database. It's the only DB that is not being replicated.

Comment: But our application continuously writes data to that collection

Comment: You can write to a collection in the local database. Also, there is nothing which can prevent you (once authorized) from writing to replication related collections such as `oplog.rs`

Comment: FYI, you should never recommend writing to `oplog.rs` or any system collections; that's an easy way to break your deployment if you're not very, very careful ;-)

Comment: Taking @Stennie's comment in account, I'll rephrase: It's technically possible to write to `oplog.rs`, not that I recommend it. **God Forbid**